# Is it possible to rounded shapes? Shapes such as hexagon, octagon?

Tags: html, css, shapes

I've been trying to round the corners of hexagon shapes for a while however I've found that none of my methods work. Do you guys have any suggestions on how it can be done?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: CSS is not a good wap to achieve this. Try SVG.

Comment: tried using svg but to no avail

Comment: @JackManey haha whathaveyoutried.com... well done brilliant find!

Comment: Probably possible with a bunch of work (and multiple elements): http://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/

Comment: @TimMedora You should post this as answer.

Answer (score 4):

http://jsfiddle.net/9BTTQ/4/

## HTML

```
<div class="hexagon">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
</div>
```

## CSS

```
.hexagon {
    position: relative;    
}

.hexagon > DIV {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 48px;
    -moz-border-radius: 16px;
    border-radius: 16px;
    width: 64px;
    height: 96px;
    background-color: blue;
}

.hexagon > DIV:nth-child(2) {
    -moz-transform: rotate(60deg);
    -ms-transfrom: rotate(60deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(60deg);
    transform: rotate(60deg);
}

.hexagon > DIV:nth-child(3) {
    -moz-transform: rotate(120deg);
    -ms-transfrom: rotate(120deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(120deg);
    transform: rotate(120deg);
}
```

Notes:

- This would probably be better done with SVG or a canvas unless it's an isolated need. Creating a bunch of elements to form a shape is both non-semantic and tedious.
- IE 7/8 won't work at all due to `transform`, `border-radius`, and `nth-child`.
- You'll notice the simple mathematical relationships between the size of the border radius, the width, and the height.
- [This site](http://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/) shows many other interesting shapes that can be generated.

Comment: Hi Tim Medora. I have a question about "the simple mathematical relationships between the size of the border radius, the width, and the height", could you help me to find the relationships? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @DonovanCharpin - Here's a modified fiddle which demonstrates the relationships: http://jsfiddle.net/9BTTQ/91/. Height = width * 1.5, and border-radius = width * .25. Honestly, I'm not sure of the geometry behind *why* this works for a rounded hexagon made of three equal rectangles.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer. In this [website](http://rechneronline.de/pi/hexagon.php), if the edge length is equal to 100, the short diagonal is about 173, so the ratio is `height = width * 1.73`. For the border radius, I can't find the value accordance with the height and the width... In the jsFiddle, I can write `border-radius: 1em / 0.5em;` which works perfectly like this [example](http://codepen.io/thebabydino/pen/gFxzt). But I have a problem with my latest version of lessCSS which calculate 2em and it's not the same as 1em / 0.5... DAMN. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9BTTQ/92/) updated

Comment: Are you trying to divide the border radius, or set unequal values on the different sides? In plain CSS, `1em / .5em` sets different border radii on sides of the rectangle. LESS CSS would divide that expression, leading to a different result. To divide in plain CSS, you would need `calc(1em / .5)`.

Comment: I would like to keep `border-radius: 1em / 0.5em;` but without `calc()`, less calculates `2em`. So I can't get this expression `border-radius: 1em / 0.5em;` with less...

Comment: The right format is just `border-radius : "1em / 0.5em";` for less... I think it works for every hexagon. Thanks for your help. +1 :)