# CSS3 or Canvas rounded hexagon

Tags: jquery, html, css, canvas

I'm trying to make a shape with CSS: a rounded hexagon (that is also elongated). I've tried thinking of a few different ways (such as a box for the body and 2 rounded triangles on the top and bottom), but I haven't come up with anything good so far. Does anyone have some ideas to create this shape in CSS?

**HTML**

```
<div id="hexagon"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
#hexagon {
    width: 100px;
    height: 55px;
    background: red;
    position: relative;
}
#hexagon:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: -25px;
    left: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 50px solid transparent;
    border-right: 50px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 25px solid red;
}
#hexagon:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -25px;
    left: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 50px solid transparent;
    border-right: 50px solid transparent;
    border-top: 25px solid red;
}
```

[image]

Comment: You can find some information here. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14665093/is-it-possible-to-rounded-shapes-shapes-such-as-hexagon-octagon

Comment: try shape from http://kizu.ru/Polygons/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks a lot, that solved the problem.

**Preview:**

http://codepen.io/melihbuyuk/pen/evrwI

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="hexagon">
    <div class="box1"></div>
    <div class="middle1"></div>
    <div class="box2"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.container { position:relative; width:500px;}

.middle1 {
    border-left: 10px solid orange;
    border-right: 9px solid orange;
    height: 188px;
    left: 35px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 59px;
    width: 181px;
    z-index:20;
    border-radius:5px;
}
.box1 {
    width:120px;
    height:120px;
    border-left: 10px solid orange;
    border-top: 10px solid orange;
    -moz-transform: scale(1) rotate(45deg) translateX(50px) translateY(-50px) skewX(-10deg) skewY(-10deg);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1) rotate(45deg) translateX(50px) translateY(-50px) skewX(-10deg) skewY(-10deg);
    -o-transform: scale(1) rotate(45deg) translateX(50px) translateY(-50px) skewX(-10deg) skewY(-10deg);
    -ms-transform: scale(1) rotate(45deg) translateX(50px) translateY(-50px) skewX(-10deg) skewY(-10deg);
    transform: scale(1) rotate(45deg) translateX(50px) translateY(-50px) skewX(-10deg) skewY(-10deg);
}

.box2 {
    width:120px;
    height:120px;
    border-bottom: 10px solid orange;
    border-right: 10px solid orange;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
    margin-top:50px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    -moz-transform: scale(1) rotate(45deg) translateX(50px) translateY(-50px) skewX(-10deg) skewY(-10deg);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1) rotate(45deg) translateX(50px) translateY(-50px) skewX(-10deg) skewY(-10deg);
    -o-transform: scale(1) rotate(45deg) translateX(50px) translateY(-50px) skewX(-10deg) skewY(-10deg);
    -ms-transform: scale(1) rotate(45deg) translateX(50px) translateY(-50px) skewX(-10deg) skewY(-10deg);
    transform: scale(1) rotate(45deg) translateX(50px) translateY(-50px) skewX(-10deg) skewY(-10deg);
}
```

Comment: Doesn't properly work in Firefox (Aurora). The top is offset. Snapshot here: http://i.imgur.com/k42Gaiy.png